# filter csrfmiddlewaretoken while posting-django

Tags: python, django, forms, csrf, django-piston

I am planning to make generic CRUD using django-piston. One of my sample code has following

```
class TaskHandler(BaseHandler):
allowed_methods = ('GET','POST',)
model = Task

def read(self, name=None):
    return self.model.objects.all()

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.has_model():
        return rc.NOT_IMPLEMENTED

    attrs = self.flatten_dict(request.POST)
    if attrs.has_key('data'):
        #  rest.POST.get('data') has csrfmiddlewaretoken as a hiddenfield
        #  i need to exclude it from post as my ORM is giving error message
        ext_posted_data = simplejson.loads(request.POST.get('data'))
        attrs = self.flatten_dict(ext_posted_data)

    try:
        inst = self.model.objects.get(**attrs)
        return rc.DUPLICATE_ENTRY
    except self.model.DoesNotExist:
        inst = self.model(**attrs)
        inst.save()
        return inst
    except self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        return rc.DUPLICATE_ENTRY
```

below is the error log

```
Piston/0.2.2 (Django 1.4) crash report:
  Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\sumit\sumit\handler.py", line 27,
      in create inst = self.model.objects.get(**attrs) 
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 131, 
      in get return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 358,
      in get clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs) 
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 621,
      in filter return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 639,
      in _filter_or_exclude clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1250,
      in add_q can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1122,
      in add_filter process_extras=process_extras)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1316,
      in setup_joins "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names))) 

    FieldError: **Cannot resolve keyword 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' into field.
      Choices are:  complete, id, name**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: don't do that.

Any user can send any POST parameters they want. You have no guarantee at all they won't add any random POST parameter even though your form does not contain it.

Instead of trying to filter `csrfmiddlewaretoken` out of your parameters, try whitelisting those you want to include. That means, only select those that are corresponding to your model fields **and** you want the user to be able to filter on them.

**Update:**
Okay, so, how to filter it out, just to satisfy your curiosity. `flatten_dict` returns a regular Python dictionary, which means you can simply `del attrs['csrfmiddlewaretoken']` to remove it from the dictionary.

**Update (2):**
To whitelist, something like the following should work:

```
allowed_keys = ['complete', 'id', 'name']
attrs = dict((key, value) for key, value in ext_posted_data if key in allowed_keys)
```

Comment: but still for self knowledge , how to filter that?

Comment: it is not working , even i tried attrs.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken')

Comment: “It is not working” does not really give much information. Where did you put the `del` statement? Does it give you an error? But really, try not to work your problem around this way, do a proper whitelist. See the answer.